# cannot launch debugger on macos using codelite

Tags: macos, codelite

I get the pop up "Failed to start terminal for debugger".i have set the gdb path in the gdb options of codelite. Is there anything else to be done?

My mac os version is 10.10.4
GDB version installed under /usr/local/bin/gdb - version 7.8.1

The c project created a simple hello world to test the codelite usage on mac os and unfortunately not able to launch gdb.The compilation is going through fine

Answer (score 2):

On OSX, the recommended the debugger is LLDB.
Please use it instead.

Project settings->general->Debugger, and select "LLDB Debugger"

EDIT, Sep 06:
I have uploaded a new OSX build (8.2.3) with this problem fixed.

http://codelite.org/support.php

Comment: thanks Eran. i have tried that as well but same issue.

Comment: Where is your project located? do you have spaces in the path? The only reason this could fail is if you have spaces in your path

Comment: I actually found the solution. I had to select the option " this is a GUI console/project" under general settings and with LLDB debugger, it worked!. Thanks

Comment: Project settings->ge ... not exist :)