# Codelite terminal and debugger quit unexpectedly

Tags: codelite

I'm taking a CSCI class and it was recommended to use Codelite for Mac. I tested out the "Hello World" program and when I debug it i get "Codelite Could not launch terminal for debugger" and when I try to run it i get "Codelite-terminal quit unexpectedly."

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed with the latest weekly build:
http://downloads.codelite.org/ (8.2.2)

Also, I answered this on this post: [cannot launch debugger on macos using codelite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908650/cannot-launch-debugger-on-macos-using-codelite)